# Includes function not picking up on .mov text in url

Tags: reactjs

Here is my url:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/roger.appspot.com/o/images%2Fd4%2FIMG_6538.mov?alt=media&token=19f7b5e7-77d6-480e-97f1-55ad9d27bb08`

I'm using `includes` to run over the URL to find `mov`

However, my function returns null

```js
// check media url to see if link left should render video or image
  useEffect(() => {
    async () => {
      if (imageUrl) {
        const isVideo = await imageUrl.includes("mp4", "mov", "MOV");

        if (isVideo) {
          return setMediaType("video");
        }
        setMediaType("image");
      }
    };
  }, [imageUrl]);
```

When I console log `mediaType` I get `null`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not doing it right

```
useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  if (imageUrl) {
                    // Why are you using await here

    const isVideo = imageUrl.includes("mp4", "mov", "MOV");

    if (isVideo) {
      return setMediaType("video");
    }
    setMediaType("image");
  }
})();
```

}, [imageUrl]);

Comment: Copy the whole code and replace it then see what happens

Comment: `'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/roger.appspot.com/o/images%2Fd4%2FIMG_6538.mov?alt=media&token=19f7b5e7-77d6-480e-97f1-55ad9d27bb08'.includes('mov','MOV')` this returns true so problem is in your code not with .includes()